# The convention regarding the use of the radical sign

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

It is well known that the expression $\sqrt[n]{z}$ (where $n$ is a natural and $z$ a complex number) is somewhat ambiguous - there are in fact $n$ complex numbers which satisfy $x^n=z$ (if $\sqrt[n]{z}$ is any one of them, then $\omega \sqrt[n]{z}, \omega^2\sqrt[n]{z},...,\omega^{n-1}\sqrt[n]{z}$ also satisfy where the $\omega $s are the roots of unity) .

In most literature though, whenever the radical sign is used this ambiguity is rarely clarified and there seems to be a convention regarding which number $\sqrt[n]{z}$ picks out unless otherwise specified.

It seems to me that the working convention is that $\sqrt[n]{z}$ refers to the root which makes the smallest angle with the real axis in the complex plane (in the counter-clockwise direction).

This explains $\sqrt{2}$ usually means the positive value, why $\sqrt{-1}$ is $i$ and not $-i$, etc.

Yet I've never seen this convention written down explicitly. I would therefore like to ask whether there is indeed such a convention?

Comment: There are a lot of questions here. As far as i is concerned, another definition would be that it is the imaginary unit that squared gives -1. It circumvents the radical -1 issue. In our university we were not even allowed to write \sqrt{-1} , but we had a fanatic professor. :)

Answer (score 2):

For positive numbers, the positive branch is generally implied. For general complex numbers, sometimes the choice is made to use the branch that includes the positive reals; however, one really should be explicit in this case.